binary division using TASM. Having hard time to get an accurate quotient when running it
This is the code, what do you think is something wrong on why it keeps producing incorrect quotient.
divide proc
    ; Set cursor position for PROMPT_1
    mov ah, 02h
    mov bh, 00h
    mov dh, 0Bh ; row
    mov dl, 0Ah ; column
    int 10h
    
    ; Display the prompt for the first number
    mov dx, offset PROMPT_1 ;(THIS IS THE FIRST BINARY INPUT)
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; Initialize the dividend to zero
    xor bl, bl

    ; Read the first binary number
    mov cx, 8
    mov ah, 01h

@DIV_LOOP_1:
    int 21h
    cmp al, 0Dh
    jne @DIV_SKIP_1
    jmp @DIV_EXIT_LOOP_1

@DIV_SKIP_1:
    and al, 0Fh
    shl bl, 1
    or bl, al
    loop @DIV_LOOP_1

@DIV_EXIT_LOOP_1:
    
    ; Set cursor position for PROMPT_2 
    mov ah, 02h
    mov bh, 00h
    mov dh, 0Ch ; row
    mov dl, 0Ah ; column
    int 10h
    
    ; Display the prompt for the second number
    mov dx, offset PROMPT_2 ;(THIS IS THE SECOND BINARY INPUT)
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; Initialize the divisor to zero
    xor bh, bh

    ; Read the second binary number
    mov cx, 8
    mov ah, 01h

@DIV_LOOP_2:
    int 21h
    cmp al, 0Dh
    jne @DIV_SKIP_2
    jmp @DIV_EXIT_LOOP_2

@DIV_SKIP_2:
    and al, 0Fh
    shl bh, 1
    or bh, al
    loop @DIV_LOOP_2

@DIV_EXIT_LOOP_2:

    ; Perform binary division
    xor ch, ch  ; quotient
    xor dl, dl  ; temporary register for subtraction result
    mov cl, bl  ; move dividend to cl

    ; Ensure divisor is not zero to avoid division by zero
    cmp bh, 0
    je @DIV_DIVISION_ERROR

    mov dl, 8  ; bit position counter

@DIV_DIVISION_SHIFT:
    shl cl, 1  ; shift left the dividend
    rol ch, 1  ; rotate left the quotient to shift in a new bit
    sub cl, bh ; attempt to subtract divisor from dividend
    jc @DIV_SUBTRACTION_FAILED
    or ch, 1   ; if no carry, set LSB of quotient
    jmp @DIV_SUBTRACTION_DONE

@DIV_SUBTRACTION_FAILED:
    add cl, bh ; restore dividend if subtraction failed

@DIV_SUBTRACTION_DONE:
    dec dl
    jnz @DIV_DIVISION_SHIFT

    ; Set cursor position for PROMPT_3
    mov ah, 02h
    mov bh, 00h
    mov dh, 0Dh ; row
    mov dl, 0Ah ; column
    int 10h
    
    ; Display the result label
    mov dx, offset DIV_PROMPT_3
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; Display the result (quotient)
    mov bl, ch
    call DISPLAY_BINARY

    ; Pause for user input
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    
    ret

@DIV_DIVISION_ERROR:
    ; Handle division by zero error
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset DIVISION_ERROR_MSG
    int 21h
    jmp @DIV_END_PROGRAM

@DIV_END_PROGRAM:
    ; Pause for user input
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    ret

DISPLAY_BINARY:
    ; Convert and display the binary number in BL
    mov cx, 8
    mov ah, 02h

@DISPLAY_LOOP:
    shl bl, 1
    jc @ONE_BIT
    mov dl, 30h
    jmp @DISPLAY_BIT

@ONE_BIT:
    mov dl, 31h

@DISPLAY_BIT:
    int 21h
    loop @DISPLAY_LOOP
    ret

; Pause for user input
mov ah, 01h
int 21h

ret

I tried different methods on solving it, but it keeps producing a wrong quotient. Can you check what is wrong with my code.
the display is like this
 PROMPT_1  DB 'INPUT FIRST NUMBER [000-111]: $'
 PROMPT_2  DB 'INPUT SECOND NUMBER [000-111]: $'


Please tell us a specific example of inputs that give the wrong output.

You should try single-stepping your code with a debugger.  Keep track of what your logic suggests the register contents should be at each step, and then when they don't match, you should be able to locate the bug.

I don't think rol is the instruction you want.  Look up its exact behavior.


it keeps producing a wrong quotient. Can you check what is wrong with my code.

Your input and output routines are fine, but the actual division algorithm is IMO not salvageable.
A trio of solutions
All the following codes will be dividing AL by BL producing a quotient in AL and a remainder in AH.
Using the byte-sized div
Nowhere in your question is there any mention of being restricted to not using the div instruction. So here it is:
  test bl, bl
  jz   @DIV_DIVISION_ERROR
  mov  ah, 0
  div  bl          ; AX / BL  ->  AL is quotient, AH is remainder

Using repeated subtraction
This is by far the simplest of the alternative solutions; (solutions that don't use the div instruction):
  test bl, bl
  jz   @DIV_DIVISION_ERROR
  mov  ah, -1    ; Temporary quotient
.a:
  inc  ah
  sub  al, bl
  jnb  .a
  add  al, bl
  xchg al, ah    ; -> AL is quotient, AH is remainder

Using trial subtraction
A lot faster and probably what you were aiming at, and still not using the div instruction:
  xor  dl, dl    ; Quotient under construction
  mov  cl, 1     ; Nominal weight of the divisor BL
  test bl, bl
  jz   @DIV_DIVISION_ERROR
  js   .Subtract ; Divisor already occupies MSB of its byte-sized container
.ShiftUp:
  shl  cl, 1     ; Adjust the weight of the current divisor
  shl  bl, 1     ; Double the current divisor
  jns  .ShiftUp  ; Until at MSB of the byte-sized container
.Subtract:
  cmp  bl, al    ; Could we borrow-less subtract current divisor from dividend ?
  ja   .Skip     ; No, then skip
  add  dl, cl    ; Add current weight to quotient under construction
  sub  al, bl    ; Lower dividend by current divisor (building remainder)
.Skip:
  shr  bl, 1     ; Try next lower divisor
  shr  cl, 1     ; Adjust to lesser weight
  jnz  .Subtract ; Repeat for as long as there is weight
  mov  ah, al    ; -> AH is remainder
  mov  al, dl    ; -> AL is quotient

